# Most recent post from every category/taxonomy but sorted by date

Tags: categories

I am trying to get a list of the most recent post from every category/taxonomy. I have found a solution for this, but I want the overall list to be **sorted by post date**. At the moment it is sorted by category/taxonomy name.

So if I post in cat A, then in Cat B and last in cat C: the post would be ordered:
C, B, A (latest first). If I then post in cat B the order should change to: B, C, A

Really would like it to work with custom taxonomy but default categories could work for me too.

The code I have so far is from this site:
http://wptheming.com/2012/08/display-the-most-recent-post-in-each-category/

```
//Retrieves all the terms from the taxonomy portfolio_category
//http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories
$cat_args = array(
    'type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'taxonomy' => 'tax_name');
$categories = get_categories( $cat_args );

    // Pulls the first post from each of the individual portfolio categories
    foreach( $categories as $category ) {
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'tax_name' => $category->slug,
            'no_found_rows' => true,
            'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
            'update_post_term_cache' => false
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        // The Loop
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div id="item">
                <b><?php the_title(); ?></b>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
        }
    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

EDIT:
I tried editing the first part of the code to:

```
$cat_args = array(
    'type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'taxonomy' => 'tax_name');
$categories = get_categories( $cat_args );
```

But it still shows the posts in order of taxonomy name?

Comment: You don't have to do everything in a single call, have you considered grabbing the latest post from each category, then sorting it, then displaying it, rather than trying to do it all in a single function call?

Answer (score 0):

In your code - Find

```
$cat_args = array(
    'type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'taxonomy' => 'tax_name');
$categories = get_categories( $cat_args );
```

Repalce

```
$cat_args = array(
    'type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'taxonomy' => 'tax_name');
$categories = get_categories( $cat_args );
```

Comment: I tried that first, but somehow it still shows the post in order of taxonomy name... :/

Comment: remove **'taxonomy' => 'tax_name'** from array **$cat_args**....

Comment: That gives me no results/post ? It also forces the code to look only at default categories. Would like it to work with my custom taxonomy ('tax_name' in this example)